# Manga with a scene where a general is forced to eat his own children(!)

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was about a hero who defeated the demon king. The princess of the kingdom sabotages him and kills him but he gets a second chance after he threatens a masochistic God.

Eventually he murders everyone in the kingdom, including making an army general eat his own kids.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @user127934 your question is illogical.  A character who kills everyone in the kingdom and makes someone eat their children is a villain, not a hero, whether he is a protatonist or an antagonist.

Comment: @M.A.Golding while all of that is technically true, there are a lot of manga and games that have 'Hero' as a title, job, or class that merely means this character has/will/is supposed to defeat the demon lord/king/other evil.  even if the do not act 'Heroic' or 'Good' in any way.  So this could still be a 'hero', just not one by a dictionary definition.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [The Dark Massacre of the Vengeful Hero](https://mangadex.org/title/34404/fukushuu-o-koinegau-saikyou-yuusha-wa-yami-no-chikara-de-senmetsu-musou-suru).

The hero defeated the demon king, was betrayed by the princess, killed, and came back because he tells the Goddess who loves him to resurrect him.  The children eating scene is chapter 11.  The hero cuts up the general's children in front of him as the hero feeds them to him.

While the hero hasn't murdered everyone in the kingdom, he has killed quite a few people.

[image]

Comment: I've added in a panel from the manga. That should help OP identify it from the visual styles used

Comment: @shuffy Your answer is incorrect.  If the protagonist kills children, in the sense of minors, to give pain to their parent, he is a villainous murderer.  If the children are adults in age, then it is possible that they are evil and deserve to die by legal execution after a trial.  But if a character kills characters for the purpose of causing pain to their parent, he is treating them like they are property belonging to their parent, instead of persons with rights and duties of their own, and thus he is violating their rights.  So this protagonist seems too evil to be a "hero".

Comment: @M.A.Golding I'm not going to debate that the protagonist is evil, however within the first two pages he is referred to as the Hero because he is the one who defeated the demon king.  Essentially, he is the "hero" not because he is good, but because of what he did before he was betrayed/killed.  "Hero" is also what most characters call the protagonist, rarely using just his name.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Hero is a 'title' not an alignment.He can either be chaotic evil or lawful good.